# i am facing 500 Internal server error! for a ajax code

Tags: javascript, ajax

I both a script for eCommerce website after install when I tried to edit any product it's throwing an error "500 Internal server error!" Then I traied to find out where is the problem. I found a  tag that has some ajax and js code. And that's the cause of the error.

```
    enter code here
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        let html = `<img src="{{ empty($data->photo) ? asset('assets/images/noimage.png') : filter_var($data->photo, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) ? $data->photo : asset('assets/images/products/'.$data->photo) }}" alt="">`;
        $(".span4.cropme").html(html);

        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });

    });


    $('.ok').on('click', function() {

        setTimeout(
            function() {


                var img = $('#feature_photo').val();

                $.ajax({
                    url: "{{route('admin-prod-upload-update',$data->id)}}",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {
                        "image": img
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                        if (data.status) {
                            $('#feature_photo').val(data.file_name);
                        }
                        if ((data.errors)) {
                            for (var error in data.errors) {
                                $.notify(data.errors[error], "danger");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });

            }, 1000);



    });
</script>
```

**How can I solve this problem please help me.**

Comment: 500 mean internal server error, please verify your server logs or console

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons for this problem. Maybe you can try to check all below:

1. Check about csrf-token send with your ajax post. Try to add _token:
   $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') into data send.
2. Check about your route.
3. DataType return
4. You need check about your server config. (htaccess, permission...)

You can view this post for more detail https://abbasharoon.me/how-to-fix-laravel-ajax-500-internal-server-error